# Paypal API Billing agreement - pending status of agreement

Tags: php, curl, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-subscriptions

I am confused on what might be an issue, payment were processed correctly, originally, but now rather than being completed straight away they are in a pending mode, for hours and haven't had a single one becoming complete yet.

I have set up a billing plan where user have to pay a monthly fee.

I went and purchased a subscription, which, if we look at API calls are done in following order and no errors in responses:
1 - Sent create agreement call and received a token.
2 - Redirect user to the Paypal site and get them to agreed to the terms.
3 - Once redirect back to the site, successfully call "Execute an agreement" and receive a subscription identification.

Paypal account doesn't have payment review switched on and I have enabled an ability to receive any currencies and duplicate payments are allowed.

When I am retrieving agreement by an id I can see that start date is 2014-07-31T14:00:00Z.
Also I have an initial payment, which is not received either.

Below is an example array used to create a billing plan:

```
    $data['description'] = 'up to 10';
    $data['type'] = 'INFINITE';

    $data['payment_definitions'] = array(array());
    $data['payment_definitions'][0]['name'] = 'Up to 10';
    $data['payment_definitions'][0]['type'] = 'REGULAR';
    $data['payment_definitions'][0]['frequency'] = 'MONTH';
    $data['payment_definitions'][0]['frequency_interval'] = '1'; 
    $data['payment_definitions'][0]['amount'] = array();
    $data['payment_definitions'][0]['amount']['value'] = '16.66';
    $data['payment_definitions'][0]['amount']['currency'] = 'AUD'; 
    $data['payment_definitions'][0]['cycles'] = '0';

    $data['merchant_preferences']['setup_fee'] = array();
    $data['merchant_preferences']['setup_fee']['value'] = '16.66';
    $data['merchant_preferences']['setup_fee']['currency'] = 'AUD';

    $data['merchant_preferences']['return_url'] = PAYPAL_RETURN_URL;
    $data['merchant_preferences']['cancel_url'] = PAYPAL_CANCEL_URL;
    $data['merchant_preferences']['auto_bill_amount'] = "YES";
    $data['merchant_preferences']['initial_fail_amount_action'] = "CONTINUE";
    $data['merchant_preferences']['max_fail_attempts'] = "0";
```

This is an example create agreement call

```
    $objDateTime = new DateTime('NOW');
    $start_date = $objDateTime->format('c'); // ISO8601 formated datetime 

    $options['name'] = "Subscription 1";
    $options['description'] = "Subscription 1";
    $options['start_date'] = $start_date;
    $options['plan'] = array();
    $options['plan']['id'] = "P-4DG30035CX372533MSFKYBFI";
    $options['payer'] = array();
    $options['payer']['payment_method'] = 'paypal';
```

This is an example agreement execute call

```
    $result = $this->paypal_curl_billing->billing_agreements_execute($token);
```

Comment: It's difficult to say why it's pending without looking up the billing plans in your account. Can you file a ticket with PayPal at www.paypal.com/mts with your account email address so that they can look up the pending billing plans and let you know why they are pending.

Comment: I have got in contact with them, hopefully will be resolved shortly. I had a look at my business paypal profile and all the payments seem to be completed now, but for testing purposes I cant really wait for a whole day to know results... and if its happening in testing it might happen in live - which is the last thing i want.